react-drag-hierarchy-tree , How to make all the parent and child height equal
I'm using react-drag-hierarchy-tree for a project, i am facing an issue with the alignment. I have a main parernt and each child has a chlid up to a level, but by having this i have a gap between the parent's first and second cell.
how do i make it all the same.
This is my code
import 'reactflow/dist/style.css';
import OrgTreeComponent, { useTree } from 'react-drag-hierarchy-tree';

const data = {
    id: 1,
    label: 'Main',
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        label: 'Parent',
        children: [
            {
                id: 3,
                label: 'child 1',
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        label: 'child 2',

                      },
                      {
                        id: 4,
                        label: 'child 2',
                      },
                      {
                        id: 4,
                        label: 'child 2',
                      },
                      {
                        id: 4,
                        label: 'child 2',
                      },
                ],
              },
              {
                id: 3,
                label: 'child 1',
              },
              {
                id: 3,
                label: 'child 1',
              },
              {
                id: 3,
                label: 'child 1',
              },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        label: 'Parent',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        label: 'Parent',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        label: 'Parent',
      },
    ],
  };
  

const CampaignStageDetails = () => {

    const { treeRef } = useTree();

    const onClick = () => {
        treeRef.current?.onExpandNodes();
      };
  
    return (
        <div>
            <OrgTreeComponent 
                data={data} 
                ref={treeRef} 
                horizontal
                collapsable={false}
                 />
        </div>
    );
}

export default CampaignStageDetails


in the reference image, i have marked with blue, i dont want that space.
Thank you
I am trying to make a table with links from one row to another

import React from 'react';
import 'reactflow/dist/style.css';
import OrgTreeComponent, { useTree } from 'react-drag-hierarchy-tree';

    const data = {
                   id: 1,
                   label: 'Main',
                   children: [
                   {
                    id: 2,
                    label: 'Parent',
                    children: [
                   {
                    id: 3,
                    label: 'child 1',
                    children: [
                    { id: 4, label: 'child 2' },
                    { id: 5, label: 'child 2' },
                    { id: 6, label: 'child 2' },
                    { id: 7, label: 'child 2' },
                   ],
                },
                   { id: 8, label: 'child 1' },
                   { id: 9, label: 'child 1' },
                   { id: 10, label: 'child 1' },
                ],
              },
                  { id: 11, label: 'Parent', children: [{ id: 12, label: 
                    'child 1' }] },
                  { id: 13, label: 'Parent', children: [{ id: 14, label: 
                    'child 1' }] },
                  { id: 15, label: 'Parent', children: [{ id: 16, label: 
                  'child 1' }] },
                  ],
                 };

                  const CampaignStageDetails = () => {
                  const { treeRef } = useTree();

                 const onClick = () => {
               treeRef.current?.onExpandNodes();
               };

               return (
           <div>
        <OrgTreeComponent data={data} ref={treeRef} horizontal 
         collapsable={false} />
         </div>
         );
       };

      export default CampaignStageDetails;


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
